# Wordpress Role Checking Levels?

Tags: php, wordpress, user-permissions

So, I am attempting to display private posts to my users that are at least a specific role.  Let's say it's `author`s.

I had thought that I could simply use `current_user_can( 'author' )` and display them if the current user is indeed at least an author or above...  however, it seems that `current_user_can` is specifically ONLY checking if the user is an 'author' and nothing else.  So, any of my users that are roles above that (editor, admin, super admin) are not able to view the ariticles.

**NOTE:**
The rest of my code works just fine, as my `author`s are indeed able to view the articles...

How can I fix this to allow a specific user role and above to be able to view my "private" articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy: you check for [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) instead.

For example:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
    // Allow access to private content
}
else {
    // This content is not for your eyes
}
```

Users with role Author and above have the `publish_posts` capability, so Editors and Administrators will also be able to access said private content. Contributors and Subscribers, on the other hand, don't have this capability and thus they won't be able to access it.

Comment: I thought about that, however, then comes the rest...   I built a plugin with a settings page.  Added a "Minimum User Role to View Private" dropdown to it.  So, while what you suggest would do he trick for that specifically, it negates the ability to set the actual "role" in plugins settings.  Unless....   unless instead of storing the role, I map the option value to the highest capability allowed for the role....

Comment: That's what I would do. Actually the people behind WordPress recommend checking for capabilities instead of roles for this very reason: "While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results." ([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)).

Comment: So... essentially, I would map Author to either `publish_posts` or `delete_publish_posts`.  Editor to `delete_pages`, etc...

Comment: appreciate it mate.  You've saved me a few brain cells today :)